# PFFile loadInBackground error 403

Tags: parse-platform, pffile

I got a problem when I load PFFile in background, parse sever will display below message

cell.pictureImage.file = product.imgoneS
cell.pictureImage.loadInBackground()

Response status code was unacceptable: 403

My Parse server run at Heroku and use MongoLab

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug in the current open source Parse code that keeps the files pointing to a parse server instead of your new heroku or other specified server.

A suggested fix is mentioned here where you can strip out the parse URL for your own.

> stripping out the "http://files.parse.com / OLDapidecrypted and replacing with my info

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/308

Edit: It seems Parse Dashboard (http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/ ) is now available which may help debug the issue but also I think they are setting up a migration for parse files.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand very much. Cloud you explain more, I had used a point to save image in column of PFObject, therefore, I use PFQuery for find object, and assign PFImageView.file = object.objectForKey("myimage") as! PFFIle; then PFImageView.loadinbackground. System will display Response status code was unacceptable: 403

Comment: BTW, My app was migrate from Parse to Heroku + MongoDB; When my app adjust link with Parse, the image will show. However, change server link to heroku. The image will display error message.